# using const variables as non type template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a question on using a `const` variable as a template argument.

The following compiles fine using gcc and clang x64 [trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/9ePdnvjM3):

```cpp
template <int N>
void func() { }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    const int x = 12;
    func<x>();
}
```

However, and as one might expect, this version of `main()` does not compile:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    const int x = argc;
    func<x>();
}
```

Shouldn't `x` be required to be `constexpr`? Or, is `const` implicitly `constexpr` when the value can be determined at compile time?

Comment: Non-type template parameters (and while we're at it, array bounds—think `int arr[x];` before you think `func<x>`) were there long before `constexpr` was invented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, a variable has to be marked `constexpr` if you want to use its value in a constant expression (meaning, in compile-time evaluation), as is required by a template argument.

However, there is an exception for `const` integral and enumeration types, which are also allowed to be used in that way, assuming that they themselves are initialized with a constant expression.

In your first example, `x` is initialized with a constant expression. In your second example, it clearly isn't (because `argc` is a function parameter).

This exception has historical reasons. It was already possible to use `const` integral/enumeration variables in this way before `constexpr` was invented (which first appearing in C++11). Without such a rule, there wouldn't have been any way to provide named non-type template arguments or array bounds before C++11, other than by a preprocessor macro (as is the case for C without VLAs). And, because old code shouldn't break needlessly with new C++ versions, this exception is still in place.

Comment: non-type template arguments would have been providable if they were literals. You just would have been unable to name them.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, not being able to use properly scoped names is what I intended to refer to.